# GoDoc add newline character

Tags: go, documentation, godoc

I know that Golang supports documentation of functions via single-line comments starting with the name of the function (spelled "func"). However, there's a nauseating side effect: having multiple single line comments will not produce a GoDoc with newline characters separating each line of text

Here's a pic to illustrate:

[image]

Here's the func, and its documentation:

```
//GetFunctionName gets function name
// Parameters:
// - `i` : Function
// **NOTE** this func fails if `i` is a variable set to a func
// (they're called "anonymous functions" in JavaScript)
func GetFunctionName(i interface{}) string {
    return runtime.FuncForPC(reflect.ValueOf(i).Pointer()).Name()
}
```

How does one insert newlines in the generated documentation? (If this were Javadoc, I would be like `<br>` and all would be good)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Insert an empty comment line, and it will be a new paragraph, meaning it will start on a new line:

```
// GetFunctionName gets function name
//
// Parameters:
//   - `i` : Function
//
// **NOTE** this func fails if `i` is a variable set to a func
// (they're called "anonymous functions" in JavaScript)
func GetFunctionName(i interface{}) string {
    return runtime.FuncForPC(reflect.ValueOf(i).Pointer()).Name()
}
```

Recommended blog post: [Godoc: documenting Go code](https://go.dev/blog/godoc)

Relevant section:

> There are a few formatting rules that Godoc uses when converting comments to HTML:
>
> - **Subsequent lines of text are considered part of the same paragraph; you must leave a blank line to separate paragraphs.**
> - Pre-formatted text must be indented relative to the surrounding comment text (see gob's doc.go for an example).
> - URLs will be converted to HTML links; no special markup is necessary.